# How to swap array values with php?

Tags: php, arrays

I try to learn about an algorithm a named Tabu Search, but I have some problem with array at 10x looping.

for example, i have an array :

```
$rute = [0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 0]
```

and i want to move the array value in 10x looping, So the results if correct like this :

```
looping 1. [0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 0]
looping 2. [0, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 0]
looping 3. [0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 0]
looping 4. [0, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
looping 5. [0, 4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 0]
looping 6. [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 0]
looping 7. [0, 4, 5, 2, 3, 1, 0]
looping 8. [0, 4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 0]
looping 9. [0, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2, 0]
looping 10. [0, 4, 1, 2, 5, 3, 0]
```

I've create a code to build it, but still wrong.

```
$rute = array(0, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 0);
$end = end($rute);
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($rute); $j++){
        if($j!==0 && ($rute[$j] !== $end)){
            $output[$i][$j] = $rute[$j];
        }else{
            $output[$i][$j] = $rute[$j];
        }
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

Comment: what's your actual question?

Comment: And because I am Thick! Please show us exactly what the difference between the I GET THIS and the I WANT THIS arrays as I cannot see any difference

Comment: And please, explain the logic !
I can see the differences but I cannot at all understand what's supposed to be going on.

Comment: You should also update your class definition syntax. the `var` syntax was used in PHP4 but never since. Are you using PHP4

Comment: the point I want to swap my array values

Comment: Ahh I see the difference now :) Silly me

Comment: :D i hope you can help me.
just think of it to hone your skills

Comment: If you edit your question to make it clear what you're asking it might be reopened. When you say you want to swap your array values, what do you mean? Swap them with what?

Comment: I have edit my question sir

Comment: Swap a[x] and a[y] means `z = a[x] ; a[x] = a[y] ; a[y] = z;` Is that your need?

Comment: I'd suggest you to show the actual results as well and do at least the preliminary analysis of differences; and then *ask an actual question*